# How to make the <li> tag next to each other?

Tags: html, css, tags

I'm new to programming anyway I'm trying to make the **li tag** next to each other. It kinda work, but I'm 99% that my code is kinda wrong.

**It should look like this:**

[Navbar-text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKGw5.png)

**CODE:**

[HTML/CSS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHGHK.png)

jsfiddle.net/gn7hczrj

Answer (score 1):

Make your li as inline-block

```
li { 
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want this?

```css
ul li {
  list-style:none;
  display:inline-block;
  background:yellow;
  border:1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Orange</li>
  <li>Banana</li>
  <li>Apple</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set the li items to ‘display: inline-block’

Comment: you should complete solution by code... `li` is a tag not answer question we can use this tag In many places and model. this question has a simple  code. please edit code. and use snippet tools .